# Another query problems

Tags: sql, vb.net

my 1st table

```
type         days        application
-------------------------------
sick          10         leave
vacation      10         leave
PSCS           0         Seminar
```

my 2nd table

```
person             type           UseDays
-----------------------------------------
chuck norris      vacation             1
chuck norris      PSCS                 0
bruce lee         sick                 5
```

and i want to join them..but i want to view only the 'leave' in application in 1st table field

ex. i select chuck norris

```
type          days          UseDays
------------------------------------
sick           10                 0
vacation       10                 1
```

here's what i already done..but still can't get the right thing..

```
SELECT      LeavetypTbl.Id, LeavetypTbl.type , LeavetypTbl.days, ISNULL(SUM(LeaveTbl.UseDays), 0) AS Expr1, LeavetypTbl.days- ISNULL(SUM(LeaveTbl.UseDays), 0) as LeftX " & _
FROM        LeavetypTbl " & _
LEFT OUTER JOIN " & _
LeaveTbl " & _
ON          LeavetypTbl.type = LeaveTbl.type And LeaveTbl.IDno = '" & id & "' and LeaveTbl.Application <> 'Seminar'" & _
GROUP BY    LeavetypTbl.type , LeavetypTbl.days, LeavetypTbl.Id"
```

and the result...will still show all the application type..

Comment: sorry there mate..need to edit it..

Comment: Please state what is your expected output, it's a bit unclear given your example with selecting chuck norris (no idea where first row comes from)

Answer (score 2):

Take smaller steps. Let's start with the types you want to have displayed. Let's filter these on `leave`. Let's call this result `A`:

```
type         days        application
-------------------------------
sick          10         leave
vacation      10         leave
```

Now let's look at the second table and filter it on the relevant person:

```
person             type           UseDays
-----------------------------------------
chuck norris      vacation             1
chuck norris      PSCS                 0
```

Now we summarize the UseDays, since there could be many vacations. The result looks quite similar. Let's call this `B`:

```
person             type      SumOfUseDays
-----------------------------------------
chuck norris      vacation             1
chuck norris      PSCS                 0
```

You know how to get to this point, right? Now let's join `A` and `B` on `type` (`SELECT ... FROM (...select-for-a...) AS A LEFT JOIN (...select-for-b...) AS B ON A.type = B.type`). Make sure to use a `LEFT JOIN`, since we want all records from A, even if no records in B exist:

```
type         days        application person      SumOfUseDays
-------------------------------------------------------
sick          10         leave       NULL              NULL
vacation      10         leave       chuck norris      1
```

We don't need the person column, so we just drop it. We still have this ugly `NULL` in SumOfUseDays, so we'll just COALESCE or ISNULL the result to 0:

```
type         days        application SumOfUseDays
-------------------------------------------------
sick          10         leave             0
vacation      10         leave             1
```

And there we are. The implementation is left as an exercise, but feel free to ask if you get stuck at a particular step.

Comment: here's what i've done..but still i get all the application type..the result the i want to get is only the 'leave' in application field......


SELECT      LeavetypTbl.Person, LeavetypTbl.Leave, LeavetypTbl.Days, ISNULL(SUM(LeaveTbl.UseDays), 0) AS Expr1, LeavetypTbl.Days - ISNULL(SUM(LeaveTbl.UseDays), 0) as LeftX  
FROM        LeavetypTbl 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                   LeaveTbl 
ON          LeavetypTbl.Leave = LeaveTbl.Leave And LeaveTbl.IDno = 'Chuck Norris' And LeaveTbl.Application ='Leave' 
GROUP BY    LeavetypTbl.Leave, LeavetypTbl.Days, LeavetypTbl.Person

Comment: @yoyieyoyie: Yes, I know, you already wrote that in your question. Did you try the step-by-step approach I suggested? How far did you get?

Comment: is this right ??  SELECT        LeavetypTbl.Leave, LeavetypTbl.Counter, LeavetypTbl.Id
FROM           (SELECT   LeavetypTbl.Leave
 From LeavetypTbl Where Application = 'Leave ') as Atbl  LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         (SELECT leaveTbl.id from LeaveTbl Where ISNULL(SUM(LeaveTbl.Numdays),0)) and i cant go on..i'm confuse in this part.. B ON A.type = B.type

Comment: In A and B you need to select *all* the fields that you need from the respective table.